# How to use "cd" to move to another folder when writing script in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am deploying my React project to Heroku.
The file structure is:

```
client

server

   package.json
```

In the `package.json`, I wrote a script like `"install-client": "cd ../client && npm install"`

But after issuing `git push heroku master`, an error as shown below occurred:

```
remote: sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ../client
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 2
remote: npm ERR! server@0.0.0 install-client: `cd ../client && npm install`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 2
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.0 install-client script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Could anyone point out where I did wrong please?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is one `package.json` running a script that works off the other? This structure makes sense, but only if the two are relatively independent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  prefix client, try this

```js
"install-client": "npm install --prefix client",
```